# How to take Line input in C language with whitespace

Tags: c

I am going through one small code where I need to take whole line as input through scanf function, and I think there is one format specifier "[^\n%*c]" can someone please tell me syntax for it and how it works?

Comment: The format specifier you show isn't complete, or even correct. Better use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) if you want to read whole lines, it's much simpler (and assuming correct arguments won't lead to buffer overflows).

Comment: `int result = scanf(" %99[^\n]", string);` where 99 is the string size -1, and it leaves the newline in the input buffer. The leading space before `%` is to consume previous whitespace. The `result` is the number of successful conversions. It is generally poor practice to try to eat *subsequent* whitespace.

Comment: You can find the "syntax and how it works" [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: `scanf()` is not the proper tool for the job. It can do it, just like an hammer can be used to drive a screw in :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char str[20];
   scanf("%19[^\n]%*c", str);
   printf("%s\n", str);
 
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to use `fgets`.

```
char str[20];
fgets(str, 20, stdin);
printf("%s", str);
```

No reason to use `scanf` here. Just remember that `fgets` also puts the newline character in the buffer. It can be removed like this:

```
str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
```